# Parsing data to a csv file on a new line - ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data that I 'get' into a new csv file. Currently, my code below posts everyone onto a single line until it fills up and then it continues to the next line.
I would like to have it where when data is imported, it starts on the following line below, creating a list of transactions.

```
def export_data
    File.open('coffee_orders.csv', 'a+') do |csv|
      puts @item_quantity = [Time.now, @item_name, @amount]
      csv << @item_quantity
    end
end
```

Comment: Don't try to create your own CSV generator. Instead, use Ruby's built-in [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class. CSV is a very-badly abused format, which can have some gotchas you won't recognize until you try to reload the data and get bitten. Your current use is simple, but it won't be that way always, and being in the habit of doing the right thing will help then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basing it on your starting code, I'd do something like:

```
def export_data
  File.open('coffee_orders.csv', 'a') do |csv|
    csv << [Time.now, @item_name, @amount].join(', ')
  end
end
```

Or:

```
def export_data
  File.open('coffee_orders.csv', 'a') do |csv|
    csv << '%s, %s, %s' % [Time.now, @item_name, @amount].map(&:to_s)
  end
end
```

Notice, it's not necessary to use `'a+'` to append to a file. Instead use `'a'` only unless you absolutely need "read" mode while the file is open also. Here's what the [IO.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-new) documentation says:

```
"a"  Write-only, starts at end of file if file exists,
     otherwise creates a new file for writing.

"a+" Read-write, starts at end of file if file exists,
     otherwise creates a new file for reading and
     writing.
```

The way I'd write it for myself would be something like:

```
CSV_FILENAME = 'coffee_orders.csv'
def export_data
  csv_has_content = File.size?(CSV_FILENAME)
  CSV.open(CSV_FILENAME, 'a') do |csv|
    csv << %w[Time Item Amount] unless csv_has_content
    csv << [Time.now, @item_name, @amount]
  end
end
```

This uses Ruby's CSV class to handle all the ins-and-outs. It checks to see if the file already exists, and if it has no content it writes the header before writing the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will add a new line after each transaction. When you append to it next, it will be from a new line.

```
def export_data
  File.open('coffee_orders.csv', 'a+') do |csv|
    csv.puts @item_quantity = [Time.now, @item_name, @amount]
  end
end
```

Although by looking the extension, you would probably want to confine it to csv format.

```
def export_data
  File.open('coffee_orders.csv', 'a+') do |csv|
    @item_quantity = [Time.now, @item_name, @amount]
    csv.puts @item_quantity.join(',')
  end
end
```